# How to handle the order of concurrent response from requests to the same API made one after the other?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, concurrency, promise, xmlhttprequest

I have an autocomplete function, when a user types something, an API call is made, and then the debounce function delays the subsequent API call until the user is typing.

Say, the user stops typing and a call is made, which returns immediately.

But the 1st call made returns after the second call is returned. The function saves the latest data received in the memory and displays the autocomplete result for the older query, but not the latest query.

How can I cancel the first request before making the second request?

Or is there a way to ignore the result from the 1st API call when the function has already received the response for the latest query?

One solution I can think of is to store the timestamp in the memory along with the data so that when the 1st request responds, I can make a check for the timestamp, and if it is older than the 2nd call, then just ignore it.

One other solution I can think of is to create a XMLHttpRequest request and then basically abort the prior request before making a new one.

It seems there is no way to abort a Promise.

Please suggest possible solutions for such a scenario.

Comment: Does an AbortController is something you can consider? You did miss the [Reproducible part](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by the way

Comment: @Novy Yes, I think that can be used. I will try to use it with a Promise to abort the prior async request. And sure, will try to add a codepen link which will reproduce the scenario. Thanks.